# What is thumbnail(0.5f) method with glide?

Tags: android

what is .thumbnail(0.5f) method and what is 0.5f in this method and why we need to use it in below code please explain.

```
Glide.with(context).load(dataList.get(position).getArtworkUrl30())
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()

                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.img);
```

Comment: Read [This](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-thumbnails) . You will get some idea about it .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

thumbnail(0.5f) sets the size of thumbnail relative to original size. 0.5f == 2 times smaller, or 50% of original size. Thumbnail is used to show preview (instead of placeholder or empty space) before fullsize image is loaded.

From documentation:

> This method is particularly useful in combinations of ListView and
>   detail views. If you already display the image in the ListView, let's
>   just say, in 250x250 pixels, the image will need a much bigger
>   resolution in the detail view. However, from the user perspective, he
>   already saw a small version of the image, why is there a placeholder
>   for a few seconds until the same image gets displayed again (in a
>   higher resolution)?
>
> In this case, it makes a lot more sense to continue to display the
>   250x250 pixel version in the detail view and in the background load
>   the full resolution. Glide makes this possible with the .thumbnail()
>   method. In this case, the parameter is a float as the size multiplier: